# Kindly explain me this code of increment decrement operator

Tags: operators, ubuntu-13.10

Following is the code that I run in ubuntu 13.10.
Code:-

```
    `#include<stdio.h>
     main()
     {
         int i=10,j=10;
         i=i++ + ++j;
         printf("i=%d j=%d\n",i,j);
         j=++i + j++;
         printf("i=%d j=%d\n",i,j);
     }
```

Output:-

```
    i=21 j=11 
    i=22 j=33
```

Logically,as per rules ans should be:-

```
    i=22 j=11
    i=23 j=35
```

And when I run this code in ubuntu 12.10 then i get correct ans i.e. above ans.
Please explain what is happening??

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code is invoking undefined behavior. Look into sequence points.

Comment: @computerfreaker Please  explain me why is it invoking undefined behaviour ? and how to look into sequence points?

Comment: It's invoking undefined behavior because the language standard says you can change a variable's value at most one time between sequence points, which are sort of steps in the program. You would look into sequence points the same way you look into anything else: Google it. @antlersoft provided you a nice explanation, too.

Comment: Ok thanks @computerfreaker.But can you explain me what should be the correct ans of given code with explanation.Please.